# Цикл с AJAX повторяет ответ на iOS

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, ios

Заметил странную особенность.

Есть несколько рекламных блоков на странице. Считаем их количество для цикла. Запускаем цикл. Внутри цикла сделал `$('IDблока').load('ссылкаНаЗагрузкуИзБазы.php');` Опустив момент что это не правильно в цикле делать запросы (изменяю уже, решение было временным) пойдем дальше. 'ссылкаНаЗагрузкуИзБазы.php' для каждого блока одна и таже. Код внутри устроен так, что грузит рекламный блок с минимальным количеством загрузок и прибавляет единичку. Благодаря этому рекламы загружаются во всех блоках разные. В идеале.

На деле так происходит на винде, во всех браузерах (включая старый сафари), на андройде (во всех популярных браузерах). Но на iOS сайт повторяет самый первый ответ от php во всех блоках. То есть рекламы выводятся одинаковые. Причем не только в Сафари, но и в хром и файрфокс.

Кто что думает? Какие могут быть причины?

Comment: Вероятно считает ссылки одинаковыми и кэширует. Попробуйте добавить какой-нибудь фиктивный параметр для изменения ссылки.

Comment: Пробовал через get передавать номер блока. Не помогло)))

Comment: `header("Cache-Control: no-cache", true)` не помогает? или можно задать директиву на самом сервере. а еще можно попробовать задать хедер при запросе. такая себе fault tolerance